# ArrayList Inquiry

Tags: java

So I am trying to take a massive text file full of integers and trying to average each line individually and round to the nearest number.

What I have done is used a scanner to pass the text file into a string array list. I then removed the white spaces in between the numbers and added that into a integer array list. I am now trying to use the Math function to do the arithmetic for each individual line. I have found no success at all.

```
237 237 235        ex. 236 for this
237 237 235        
237 237 235
237 237 235
237 237 235


ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> integerNumberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

File file = new File("3.txt");
Scanner list = new Scanner(file);

while(list.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = list.nextLine();
    s = s.replaceAll(" ", "+");
    numberList.add(s);
}
for(int i = 1; i<numberList.size(); i++) {
    int number = Integer.valueOf(numberList.get(i));
    integerNumberList.add(number);

}
for(int j = 0; j<integerNumberList.size(); j++) {
    int newnumber = Integer.valueOf(integerNumberList.get(j));
}
```

I have not done the average code yet since I can not even get the numbers to add.

Comment: So what problem are you hitting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "237+237+235"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at TEE.main(TEE.java:22)                                                                                         Pretty much I am not able to do the math of adding the three numbers in each index of the arraylist. I want to add within the array index

Comment: Use `scanner.nextInt()` to get the individual ints of each line. something like `while (sc.hasNextLine()) { while (sc.hasNextInt()) { intList.add(sc.nextInt()); } sc.nextLine(); }`

Comment: **I then removed the white spaces in between the numbers and added that into a integer array list** No, you have replaced the white spaces with plus symbols and added the concatenated string consisting of digits and the plus symbol to your list. List add does not do what you might think it does. It will definetly not sum your numbers.

Comment: @Aaron Once I do that how can I add every three numbers? Remember I need to average each row which consists of three numbers.

Comment: @davidugil - Didn't you use the solution which I've posted? I thought you would have used the solution and completed your work. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @davidugil might want to edit your question, because it reads like you need an average of all the numbers of your file rather than of each line. Anyway just use `while (sc.hasNextLine()) { double lineAverage = (sc.nextInt()+sc.nextInt()+sc.nextInt())/3.0; sc.nextLine()}` then if your lines consistently have 3 ints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are replacing space with `+` and therefore each line is getting converted into a string e.g `237+237+235` which is not an integer string which can be parsed to an integer.

You need to split each line by space(s) which will return an array of integer strings. You can then iterate the array and add each integer to `numberList`.

Do it as follows:

```
while (list.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = list.nextLine();
    String[] nums = str.split("\\s+");// Split on space(s)
    for (String s : nums) {
        numberList.add(s);
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

As per your comment, all you want is to add the average of each line into a `List`. This will require a couple of more statements as shown below:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
List<Double> numsAvgList = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] nums = str.split("\\s+");// Split on space(s)
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (String s : nums) {
        sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
    numsAvgList.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(sum / nums.length).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
}

// Display average list
System.out.println(numsAvgList);
```

### Demo

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        List<Double> numsAvgList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String str = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] nums = str.split("\\s+");// Split on space(s)
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (String s : nums) {
                sum += Double.parseDouble(s);
            }
            numsAvgList.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(sum / nums.length).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
        }

        // Display average list
        System.out.println(numsAvgList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[236.33, 236.33, 236.33, 236.33, 236.33]
```

**The content of the file:**

```
237 237 235
237 237 235        
237 237 235
237 237 235
237 237 235
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think I phrased my question incorrectly.  What I am attempting to do is take three numbers.   ex) 0 0 1.  And then average these numbers to 0 0 0 because the average rounds down. But I want to do this for each individual line and every line has three numbers so I want to know how I can average all three together and not separate them.

Comment: @davidugil - Check the update.

Comment: Yes your code works great! The only thing is rounding up or down to the nearest whole number but I think can be achieved with the math function rint? In other words it needs to be 236, 236, 236 etc

Comment: You can check [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bigdecimal-biginteger) to learn more about rounding.